# returned php JSON split into 2 Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I do the following in php

```
foreach($QuestionAsekd as $k => $v){
    $grp_name = $v['NAME'];
    $groupValues[$grp_name][] = array('label'=> $v['ASSESSDATE'],'y'=> $v['VALUE']);
}
$jsonformat=json_encode($groupValues);
return jsonformat;
```

If I do a console.log on it in JQuery, I get the following

```
  '{"Anxiety":[{"label":"03-01-2017","y":"18"},{"label":"11-01-2017","y":"15"}],"Depression":[{"label":"03-01-2017","y":"19"},{"label":"11-01-2017","y":"12"}]}'
```

Which I would like to turn into

```
var HADS_dps1 = [{ label: "03-01-2017", y: 18 },{ label: "11-01-2017", y: 15 }];
var HADS_dps2 = [{ label: "03-01-2017", y: 19 },{ label: "11-01-2017", y: 12 }];
```

Im not to familiar with Javascript and I tries splitting splicing and manualy building the objects above, but I dont have a clue.

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting a response object which contain two keys Anxiety and Depression. You can directly assigning these values like

```
var HADS_dps1 = response.Anxiety;
var HADS_dps2 = response.Depression;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do

```
x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

See the documentation for parseJSON here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing everything in that php file you can try this

```
<script>
data = jQuery.parseJSON($jsonformat);
var HADS_dps1 = data.Anxiety;
var HADS_dps2 =  data.Depression;
</script>
```

If youare doing a restful call to php
try this

```
$http.get("url").success(function(data){
    var HADS_dps1 = data.Anxiety;
    var HADS_dps2 =  data.Depression;
}
```